# Не выводит данные на DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

Пишу простую программу базы данных на c# в Windows Form. По индусским гайдам привязал datasource. Но почему-то DataGridView не показывает информацию.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace LibrarianAppNew
{
    public partial class Form : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        public Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void DataGridView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string cs = "Data Source = Books.db; Version = 3;";
            SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(cs);
            cnn.Open();          
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapt = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Books", cnn);           
            adapt.Fill(dt);
            DataGridView.DataSource =dt;
            cnn.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось вот с этим вариантом:

Я сделал альтернативную программу. И она показывает корректно. Но почему у меня первый вариант не получился - я не понимаю.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace LibrarianApp
{   
    public partial class Start : Form       
    {
        //private DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
        //private BindingSource BinS = new BindingSource();
        public Start()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Start_Load();
        }
        private void Start_Load()
        {
                //BindingSource BinS = new BindingSource();
                //BinS.DataSource = GetData("Select * From Books");               
                dataGridView1.DataSource = GetData("Select * From Books");
                dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders;
                dataGridView1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;        
        }
        private static DataTable GetData(string SQLiteCommand)
        {
            string conString = "Data Source=Books.db;Version=3;";
            SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(conString);
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(SQLiteCommand, cnn);
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);

            return table;
        }
    }    
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]